# Transferring all rows of a MySQL table to another

Tags: mysql

I want to bulk insert all rows from one table to another. I am confused on how to use Select with Insert. Is there a way that a new table is automatically created if it does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

One is to [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html), which will insert the resultset of your query into an existing table with the same data structure as your query

```
INSERT INTO MyTable_Backup
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

The other is to [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html), which will create a new table based on the data structure of your query an insert the resultset.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable_Backup
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

However one thing to note is that this will not match the indexes of the source table. If you need indexes, you need to add them manually.

Answer (score 2):

[trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) and/or [select into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) are recommended here